# Android Webview url not loading

Tags: android, android-webview

Few urls are not loading in the webview. Please check the code. If i load google it loads properly. Any Solution? URL LOADS PROPERLY IN THE BROWSER.

Here this url (and few others also) is not loading wv.loadUrl("http://resident.uidai.net.in/get-enroled");
Instead if google is loaded it loads properly. How can i forcefully load this url?

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    wv = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wvHome);
    wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    wv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    try {
        wv.loadUrl("http://resident.uidai.net.in/get-enroled");
        //wv.loadUrl("http://eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        wv.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
    {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }

}
```

Comment: @Onik Yup it loads properly in the browser.

Comment: `Server not found` on my `Ubuntu` laptop with `Firefox`...

Comment: @Onik Here its working fine... Windows Laptop with Chrome
Is there any solution. How can i forcefully load the url?

Comment: @AnkushKapoor change url to https see my solution below

Comment: @SalvatoryBaya tried but its not working.... When i open the url in the mobile browser it shows Certificate Error. Even the method onReceivedSslError is overridden but still url is not opening in the app

Comment: @AnkushKapoor where are you using the HelloWebViewClient class?

Comment: @SalvatoryBaya didn't get you.... i have used The HelloWebViewClient Class as mentioned in the code in the question.

Comment: I don't see anywhere on your code where you're using it. I mean something like this  wv.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

Comment: @SalvatoryBaya ohhh yes.... i used wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); instead of HelloWebViewClient :P  :P ...... My bad :P 

Anyways Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st. change http to https

2nd. Change wv.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

3rd. override the following

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
}

}
```